# How should our devs test python SVN branches with Jenkins?

Tags: python, svn, jenkins, continuous-integration, release

I am working on a web project with 7 developers. I setup a beta box (debian) so that we can do testing of new code before passing it to staging.

On the beta box, I setup Jenkins and would like to automate the merge/testing process. We also have a test suite which I would like to tie-in somehow.

How should I test and run python web projects with SVN / Jenkins?

I'm trying to formulate a good workflow. Right now each developer works on a feature branch, I run the code in the branch, if it looks good we merge it.

I would love to have developers login to the beta jenkins, and tell it to build from their feature branch. Here is my plan for what Jenkins would do:

1. Make sure the feature branch is rebased from trunk
2. Make sure the beta branch is identical to trunk (overwriting any merged-in feature branches)
3. Merge the feature branch into the beta branch
4. Kill the running server
5. Start the server `nohup python app.py &`
6. Run the test suite `python test.py`
7. Output the test data to the developer's view in Jenkins
8. If any of the tests fail, revert to the state before the branch was merged

I'm not sure how to handle merge conflicts. Also, the above is probably bad and wrong. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: To work with feature branches I will strongly recommend you to work with an DVCS. If you and your team are forced to use svn you can always use git-svn (or similar) so you can do the development with git and then have the svn as a central repository.

Comment: I wish I could use Git for this. I am a huge fan of Git, and don't see any reasons to use SVN. Unfortunately my team thinks otherwise. I'm worried that adding git-svn further complicates an already complex release process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is a bit too big to be answered in a simple post, I will therefore try to give a few hints and references as far as I see from my personal view:

A few quick tips:

- I like the idea of separating the developers into branches, but I would do the testing on the feature-branch and only merge to the beta branch if the feature passes tests, this way nothing enters beta until it is tested!
- I would put the integration steps into a script outside of Jenkins. Make it part of the source code. This way you can test the script itself quickly outside of Jenkins
- Use the build-system or scripting language you feel most comfortable with, most of the steps can easily done with any programming language
- Make the script return success or failure, so Jenkins can flag the build as failed
- For the merge-issues, you have two possibilities

  - Require the branch to be manually rebased before a developer can submit it for integration, check in the script and fail it if a rebase is necssary. This way merge-errors cannot happen, the build simply fails if the branch is not rebased
  - If you rather allow non-rebased merges, you need to fail the build on merge errors so the developer can manually resolve the problem (by rebasing his/her branch before submitting again)

Here some books that I found useful in this area:

- How Google Tests Software, by James A. Whittaker, Jason Arbon, Jeff Carollo
- Continuous Delivery: Reliable Software Releases through Build, Test, and Deployment Automation by Jez Humble

Let me know via comments what additional content you would like to have.

Answer (score 3):

There are few things:

- As barracel suggested - it would be much more convenient  to use some DVCS - such git is much better prepared to work in the multiple branches.
- IMHO process of merging is something which you rather don't want to
  automate (I write about this referring to 'how to handle merge conflicts'). In workflows which I used to work - merge was always processed by human, sometimes with some kind of code review (I am not sure what do you mean by ' if it looks good ' - do you verify only functionality or also how it was implemented to have an orientation?
- Besides of unittests - make some functional tests (Selenium) and also performance tests (jmeter or tsung) launched after every merge to beta branch - in that way you will be tracing also how application is changing with the development (and maybe react in time - for example if you will notice decrease of performance during login page, for instance.
- It is trivial thing, but during work on separate branches - make sure about flow of the information so you will avoid developing same parts in different branches, or growing contradictory in used solutions / patterns / libraries. What may help - sending emails with fails  (to developer who failed) and to everyone after successfully merge to the trunk - so everyone will be informed (but make sure that you are not spamming developers - they will stop reading it ;)
- If you really have a lot of merge conflicts - maybe it is time to reconsider flow and minimize number of branches, interesting readings http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2010/02/24/branching-strategies-the-cost-of-branching-and-merging/ or Branch By Abstraction http://paulhammant.com/blog/branch_by_abstraction.html/
- Make sure that developers are pulling and merging trunk to their branches often - it should also help with reducing conflicts, or even
- Why not test directly on developer branches after merging from trunk? Such merged code, once again should be easy to merge back into the trunk

Comment: Typically we just verify functionality. Can you recommend the best tools for doing conflict resolution? Possibly one that integrates with Jenkins?